# SocketIO with ChangeStream Mongodb in NodeJs APIs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, socket.io

"I am working on a Node.js and Express.js backend application developed using TypeScript. This application serves CRUD APIs and interacts with MongoDB to manage data from hardware devices and sensors, which provide real-time data updates. These APIs are consumed by a Flutter mobile application.

I am currently faced with a requirement to implement Socket.IO for specific GET request APIs. The objective is to efficiently send real-time updates and newly inserted documents to the Flutter mobile application without repeatedly invoking the API.

For instance, in a GET request API, I am utilizing Mongoose queries to retrieve and return all documents in response to each API call. However, I aim to implement Socket.IO in a way that updates and new data are pushed to the Flutter app as they occur, without the need for repeated API calls.

How can I effectively integrate Socket.IO into my existing architecture for these GET request APIs to achieve this real-time data synchronization between the backend and the Flutter application?"

I have tried to implement the same requirement by creating seperate nodejs project, but when i implement same way in my current typescript application. I am facing lots of issues and my approach not working. Is there any easy way to fulfill this requirement.